# How to traverse Grails maps in jQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, grails, dictionary

So, I obtain a set of results in my controller via SQL and pass it into the GSP, I then stick this data into a hidden field and looks like so: -

```
[
{forms_idx=0, form_id=21, events_idx=0, event_id=110, object_id=2, value=null},
{forms_idx=0, form_id=21, events_idx=1, event_id=109, object_id=3, value=null}, 
{forms_idx=1, form_id=22, events_idx=0, event_id=112, object_id=2, value=null}, 
{forms_idx=1, form_id=22, events_idx=1, event_id=111, object_id=1, value=null}, 
{forms_idx=2, form_id=23, events_idx=0, event_id=114, object_id=2, value=null}, 
{forms_idx=2, form_id=23, events_idx=1, event_id=113, object_id=3, value=null}
]
```

I then pass this through to a jQuery function via this: -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
testing($("#myresults").val());
});
```

I know this works because I've tried it with a simple static value and then put an alert into the testing function.

My question is, how do I put a simple loop of some kind into my function now to address the results in the data I've passed it?!  I've tried each etc but its not working and I'm probably missing something really basic, any suggestions?  This is what I'm currently trying...

```
function testing(results){
    $.each(results, function(index, value){
        alert(index + " " + value)
    })
}
```

I also tried this but just got the value `undefined` back...

```
function testing(results){
alert(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that hidden field holds String of data whilst you want to use it as it would be JSON. Your options:

- Have separate method in controller which returns JSON data:

  ```
  import grails.converters.JSON;

  class MyController {
      def showData() {
          def myData = [some:'map']
          render myData as JSON
      }
  }
  ```

  Then in your javascript:

  ```
  $.getJSON('my/showData',function(jsonData){
      console.log( "Data ready to be used: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData) );
  });
  ```
- Or print out JSON in javascript variable instead of hidden field:

  ```
  <%@ page import="grails.converters.JSON" %>
  <r:script disposition="head">
      var myData = ${dataFromModel as JSON};
      console.log( "Data ready to be used: " + JSON.stringify(myData) );
  </r:script>
  ```
- Or have custom javascript parser to convert your string to JSON object

  ```
  // TODO create parser :)
  ```

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply but printing out JSON in a javascript variable instead of using a hidden field appears to do exactly what I need, many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<%@ page import="import grails.converters.JSON" %>
$(document).ready(function () {
    testing($("#myresults").val().encodeAsJSON());
});
```

although it would make more sense to put your data in the model rather than a hidden field...